# Limiting access to features of web application based on the edition purchased

Tags: asp.net-mvc, encryption, licensing

I have a ASP.NET MVC web application that is supposed to be sold in various editions with each edition unlocking more and more features of the application. Think something like editions of Visual Studio - Professional allows you to do X and Y, but with Premium, you can also do Z.

I am trying to enhance the application so that it would possible to reliably determine which edition was actually purchased. Or, in other words, to somehow store the information about the edition so that it is easily accessible by the application. I am not looking for any fancy protection mechanism, just something that would make cracking the app more complicated than rewriting some plaintext file :)

One way I could think of is to use public/private key pair. 
I generate a licence key carrying the edition payload, encrypt it with the private key, and send it to a customer. The customer then inputs the encrypted licence key, which gets stored somewhere, e.g. a database. The public key would be hard-coded to our webapp, so that the app can decrypt the licence key and decide whether to allow access to some feature or not.

This would *probably* work, but it somehow seems lame to have the public key hard-coded. Is there some alternative to the solution proposed above (perhaps I am trying to reinvent the wheel here)? Are there any glaring flaws with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is good that you are not trying to achieve perfect security, because you are trying to implement some kind of content protection scheme, and those are bound to fail without explicit support of the application environment (e.g. OS) - and they will mostly fail even then.

Normally you don't encrypt with a private key, you *sign* with a private key. You could send a public key with the application and verify within your application that the edition was signed for that particular public key.

There are a lot of ways to attack this scheme, and it can be enhanced by obscuring some more, but that's basically all you can do.

Comment: Thanks for that. I realize that using a private key in a way I described is not a standard thing to do. The signing approach you outlined can work with pre-defined set of editions, but what if I need my licence key to carry some additional, arbitrary payload - e.g. max number of users allowed? In that case, I suppose I would really need do decrypt the key to see the actual number. Is it that bad to use private key for encryption?

Comment: You should not use a private key for that. You can use a public key and give the user a token, signed by the private key. Then you use the public key within the application to verify the token. You would only use a private key within the application if the application would have to authenticate itself, e.g. against an online server, or to make itself known when requesting upgrades.